# I want to add the above date to each line on a prstat log file

Tags: logs, date, time, timestamps

I have a prstat log, as you all know the date and time is recorded on the top of the log file, I would like to add that date and time to the begging of each line until it gets to a new date, then I would do the same for that part of the log.

Is this possible?, is there a way to do this through commands or a script, I would've created a script to do so, but it's too late as the data has already been collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming date format is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss you can use this perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

open(FILEH,"<","your.log") or die "cannot open file";
my $date = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";

while(<FILEH>) {
    if( /^([A-Z][a-z]{2}\s[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s[0-9]+\s[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\s[0-9]{4})$/ ) {
        $date = $1;
    }
    else {
        print "$date $_";
    }
}
```

Change your.log with full path of your log file.

Comment: I've modified the pattern for date. Which is the full path?

Comment: The regex matched the timestamp in the logs correctly, but for some reason its printing the default 000-00-00 00:00:00 on each line, I cant see why, the perl script is correct by finding the timestamp and printing it when it reaches a line where it doesnt, but I cant find out why its printing the default value only...

Adding the full path worked btw

Comment: If it is printing the default I don't think it matches the timestamp correctly. Can you give me a real timestamp example?

Comment: Actually this is my fault, I did not explain my question properly, you see a prstat log has multiple chunks of lines, after another second or so, another chunk is then logged with a new timestamp above it, on top of each chunk looks something like this:
### (1311344015) Thu Dec 13 01:03:35 2012

Comment: I tested your regex with an online perl regex tester and its matching it perfectly

Comment: I've used ^ and $ to match lines which contains only timestamps. You can remove them and I think it will work. But this way it will match also timestamps inside lines if they have the same format.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know python much more, but i tried

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

Each_line = [line.split() for line in open('/tmp/prstat.log')]

for n in xrange(len(Each_line)):
    if '2008' in Each_line[n]:
         print " ".join(Each_line[n])," ".join(Each_line[n+1])
```